# Fetch document by passing array of objects in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can we fetch documents from the mongo db collection by passing an array of objects in node js server. For an example,

```
var arr = [
     { "name": "ABC", "location": "NY"},
     { "name": "CDE", "location": "LA"},
     { "name": "EFG", "location": "NZ"}
];
```

here, objective is to fetch the documents, which are all satisfies this name and location combination.

Comment: You could use the `db.collection.find()`, more information https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Answer (score 0):

Given the array you specified, you can actually just the array in an [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query (assuming Mongoose), it looks for documents with either of those 3 conditions fulfilled:

```
var arr = [
    { "name": "ABC", "location": "NY"},
    { "name": "CDE", "location": "LA"},
    { "name": "EFG", "location": "NZ"}
];

Model.find({$or: arr}, function(err, docs) {
      // do something with docs, docs are the documents returned from the query
});
```

Model being the model/schema for the collection you are using.

Comment: No, its not returning the data. If any one of the object is not exists in the collection then also can we get the result. But $or returns me empty array

Comment: can you provide an example of what you are talking about above? i don't think i quite understand what you are trying to do. the answer I gave will return documents that fulfill one of those conditions, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to fetch store details from the store collection where the itemName, itemRef, itemCategory, itemSpecification matches. My passing payload is in array as mentioned in the sample.

Comment: original passing payload is,                                                                       option:
[ { ref: '5794db53a7dd0eb45311e8d5', item: 'File',uom: 'Piece',    specification: 'Clear Folder File A4',category: 'Office' },                                  
  { ref: '5794db3ba7dd0eb45311e8cb', item: 'Letter Tray', uom: 'Piece',
    specification: 'ALFAX ', category: 'Office' },
  { ref: '5794d705a7dd0eb45311e882', item: 'GPS Tracking Device',
    uom: 'Piece',specification: 'T333 E-Meitrack', category: 'Project' } ]

Comment: are you sure your documents have all those keys?  your "ref" key looks like something that would be stored as an _id as ObjectId('5794db53a7dd0eb45311e8d5')

Comment: Yes, but i am storing it in db as ref only. I am referring this ObjectId('5794db53a7dd0eb45311e8d5') from another collection

Comment: Ok can you check one at a time that each element of the array returns a document? Are you also using mongoose or mongodb-native?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118287/discussion-between-nithya-neela-and-devonjs).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested solution to your query.

```
var filter = {
      $or: arr
}
db.coolection.find(filter, function(err, docs){
      //your functionality
});
```

This will help.